# How to silence paramiko CryptographyDeprecationWarnings in ansible

Tags: ansible, paramiko

I'm running Ansible 2.7.6 on macOS.

Every time I run a playbook, I get the same warning over and over:

*/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py:164: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point*

I know the problem is with the paramiko Python library that ansible is using.  This is due to be fixed in the next version, but it's not out yet.  Is there an easy way to suppress these warnings for now?

Comment: Can you share version? Also check this:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1369 :
`pip install cryptography==2.4.2`

Comment: I was running cryptography 2.5.  Downgrading to 2.4 shut it up for now, but I'm still searching for a way to use 2.5 and have it keep quiet.

Answer (score 6):

Execute the following command before executing Ansible

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::UserWarning
```

Alternatively, you can set it in `~/.bash_profile`